# Create and fill an associative array of multiples dimensions

Tags: php, arrays, dimensions, associative

I'm currently trying to create an associative array which will have two dimensions and I think a solution for this probleme could resolve problemes for array with more dimensions.

I recover data with an API which look like that :

```
   {
        "item_id": "89",
        "name": "Confiture de Myrtilles",
        "product_id": "737",
        "meta_key": "vmm_warehouse_sg_10783",
        "meta_value": "0"
    },
    {
        "item_id": "89",
        "name": "Confiture de Myrtilles",
        "product_id": "737",
        "meta_key": "vmm_warehouse_sg_10782",
        "meta_value": "0"
    },

    {
        "item_id": "91",
        "name": "Poires Guyot (bio)",
        "product_id": "690",
        "meta_key": "_backorders",
        "meta_value": "no"
    },
    {
        "item_id": "91",
        "name": "Poires Guyot (bio)",
        "product_id": "690",
        "meta_key": "_sold_individually",
        "meta_value": "no"
    },
```

I just want to create an array like this :

```
            array[item_id->[meta_key->meta_value]]
```

So I have to recover the item_id which will have the role of the secondth array and after put in this array the meta_key and meta_value associated.

So for example I will have an array like this :

Products[89]["vmm_warehouse_sg_10783"->"0"
             "vmm_warehouse_sg_10782"->"0"]

And an other like this :

Products[91][........]

At the end, I will have a final array like this :

```
Products [ [89]->{"vmm_warehouse_sg_10783"->"0","vmm_warehouse_sg_10782"->"0"}
           [91]->{.....}]
```

I have already tried something but I'm just a beginner and I don't found solution for my problem.

```
$Products = $this->wpdb->get_results( $SQL_Deliveries );
//this line allow $Products to recover all data from the API


foreach ( $Products as $Product ) {
    $Meta_products[] = Product->item_id;
    foreach($Product as $Product_meta){
    $Meta_products[$item_id]->{Product_meta->meta_key,Product_meta
        ->meta_value);
    }
```

I'm sure I did mitakes in my code too, but I really don't know how to resolve this problem. Thank you for your participation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a multidimensional object array.

There is a little bit of fiddling involved to declare nested objects.  The curly bracing is also necessary.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NOioC))

```
$products = [
    (object)["item_id"    => "89",
     "name"       => "Confiture de Myrtilles",
     "product_id" => "737",
     "meta_key"   => "vmm_warehouse_sg_10783",
     "meta_value" => "0"
    ],
    (object)["item_id"    => "89",
     "name"       => "Confiture de Myrtilles",
     "product_id" => "737",
     "meta_key"   => "vmm_warehouse_sg_10782",
     "meta_value" => "0"
    ]
];
    $result = (object)[];
    foreach($products as $product) {
        if (!isset($result->{$product->item_id})) {
            $result->{$product->item_id} = (object)[];
        }
        $result->{$product->item_id}->{$product->meta_key} = $product->meta_value; 
    }

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
(object) array(
   '89' => 
  (object) array(
     'vmm_warehouse_sg_10783' => '0',
     'vmm_warehouse_sg_10782' => '0',
  ),
)
```

Alternatively, to generate the nested object structure, you could build an array of arrays, then use `json_encode()`, then `json_decode()` on the result.

---

If you want an array as output, that's easiest:
Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nLrXZ))

```
$products = [
    (object)["item_id"    => "89",
     "name"       => "Confiture de Myrtilles",
     "product_id" => "737",
     "meta_key"   => "vmm_warehouse_sg_10783",
     "meta_value" => "0"
    ],
    (object)["item_id"    => "89",
     "name"       => "Confiture de Myrtilles",
     "product_id" => "737",
     "meta_key"   => "vmm_warehouse_sg_10782",
     "meta_value" => "0"
    ],
    (object)["item_id"    => "91",
     "name"       => "Poires Guyot (bio)",
     "product_id" => "690",
     "meta_key"   => "_backorders",
     "meta_value" => "no"
    ],
    (object)["item_id"    => "91",
     "name"       => "Poires Guyot (bio)",
     "product_id" => "690",
     "meta_key"   => "_sold_individually",
     "meta_value" => "no"
    ]
];

$result = [];
foreach($products as $product) {
    $result[$product->item_id][$product->meta_key] = $product->meta_value; 
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  89 => 
  array (
    'vmm_warehouse_sg_10783' => '0',
    'vmm_warehouse_sg_10782' => '0',
  ),
  91 => 
  array (
    '_backorders' => 'no',
    '_sold_individually' => 'no',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what are you trying to achieve, but I suppose you want associative array with id as the key and array of meta_key and meta_value as its value?

If so, then:

```
foreach ( $Products as $Product ) {
    $Meta_products[$Product->item_id][$Product->meta_key] = $Product->meta_value;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I want to put all meta_key and meta_value together if they have the same item_id. You have two array in my example of API answer. Both have the same item_id so I just want to create One array which will have the name of "index_id" and inside you will have all meta_key and meta_value.

Comment: @JulienTxerriakGuillou Ive edited my answer, now you can access your data by eg. `$Meta_products[89]["vmm_warehouse_sg_10783"]`